# vim: using a for-loop-iterator-variable in a search pattern

Tags: text-processing, scripting, vim

I am trying to use a for loop iterator variable in a vim search pattern to determine for a range of words how man times they occur in a file. What I do so far is:

```
for i in range(1,40) | %s/SiTg//gn | endfor
```

I need the iterator variable `i` in the search pattern `%s/S\iTg//gn` to be bound by the for loop. How can I achieve this in vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

In your example, you want to place the `i` variable into the `:%s` command:

```
for i in range(1,40) | execute '%s/S' . i . 'Tg//gn' | endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the `for` loop for other purposes, you can always expand your regex to cover the whole range of numbers:

```
:%s/S\([1-4]0\|[1-3]*[1-9]\)Tg//gn
```

Comment: Cheers. I need the for loop to consecutively show me for each specific word how many matches there were. E.g. `S1Tg` four times, `S2Tg` four times, `S3Tg` four times etc.

Comment: @brauner I see. I'm afraid you'll need to wait for a `vim` guru for this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a pure vim solution. With a `for` loop and `grep` it's quite easy: `for I in {1..40}; do grep -c "S${I}Tg" FILE; done`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\=<subexpression>` modifier, e.g.: `:s/a/\=g:integer."a"/g` ← it'll prepend all letters `a` with the `g:integer`'s value.